# installing GDAL 1.10 Complete needed to run rgdal package?

Tags: gdal, rgdal

I am starting to work with Rstudio and have to work with spatial data. This question relates to my previous question about installing rgdal. I work on a Macbook pro with OSX10.7.5. Do I need to install GDAL 1.10 Complete as an installer in order to install some R packages? I can download these from: http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks. Is this a good idea?
Thank you in advance, Sarah

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/index.html):

> "rgdal provides bindings to Frank Warmerdam's Geospatial Data Abstraction Library (GDAL) (>= 1.6.3) and access to projection/transformation operations from the PROJ.4 library."

So yes, in order to use rgdal in R you need to GDAL complete.